# For or while loop for char and more in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

Apologise for some Korean alphabet if you don't understand.

I would like to print out this whole for 3 more times using loop and I couldn't figure out since yesterday.
this program prints 1 person's information now but I need to take 2 more people's information and then print total 3 people's information using loop and then sort with ascending order from the birth year but I think I can figure that out if I can make this runs with loop first...

I tried for loop but it didn't work and can't think of any solution with my current level.
Please let me know if you need more explanation. It is my first time using stackoverflow clearly, I have no idea how to use it well... 
I would be appreicated for any advices.

Thanks in advance for your help

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        char name[20];
        char major[50];
        char ssn[20];

        // gets name, major, ssn
        printf("%s", "이름 : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name);
        printf("%s", "학과 : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", major);
        printf("%s", "주민등록번호 : ");
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", ssn);

        // last 2 digits of birth year
        char year[3];
        memcpy(year, &ssn[0], 2);
        year[2] = '\0';

        // 2 digits of birth month
        char month[3];
        memcpy(month, &ssn[2], 2);
        month[2] = '\0';

        // 2 digits of birth day
        char day[3];
        memcpy(day, &ssn[4], 2);
        day[2] = '\0';

        // distinguising birth years of 1900
        char fullyear[5];
        if ((ssn[6] == '1') || (ssn[6] == '2') || (ssn[6] == '5') || (ssn[6] == '6'))
        {
            fullyear[0] = '1';
            fullyear[1] = '9';
            fullyear[2] = year[0];
            fullyear[3] = year[1];
            fullyear[4] = '\0';
        }

        // distinguishing birth years of 2000
        if ((ssn[6] == '3') || (ssn[6] == '4') || (ssn[6] == '7') || (ssn[6] == '8'))
        {
            fullyear[0] = '2';
            fullyear[1] = '0';
            fullyear[2] = year[0];
            fullyear[3] = year[1];
            fullyear[4] = '\0';
        }

        // distinguishing birth years of 1800
        if ((ssn[6] == '9') || (ssn[6] == '0'))
        {
            fullyear[0] = '1';
            fullyear[1] = '8';
            fullyear[2] = year[0];
            fullyear[3] = year[1];
            fullyear[4] = '\0';
        }

        // print name
        printf("%s, ", name);
        // print birth year
        printf("%s년 ", fullyear);
        // print month
        printf("%s월 ", month);
        // print day
        printf("%s일, ", day);

        // leap year, converting from full year string --> int
        int leapyear;
        leapyear = atoi(fullyear);
        if (((leapyear % 4 == 0) && (leapyear % 100 != 0)) || (leapyear % 400 == 0))
        {
            printf("윤년, ");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("윤년아님, ");
        }

        // foreigner or Korean
        if ((ssn[6] == '5') || (ssn[6] == '6') || (ssn[6] == '7') || (ssn[6] == '8'))
        printf("외국, ");
        else printf("대한민국, ");

        // gender
        if ((ssn[6] == '1') || (ssn[6] == '3') || (ssn[6] == '5') || (ssn[6] == '7') || (ssn[6] == '9'))
        printf("남자, ");
        else printf("여자, ");

        // print major
        printf("%s\n\n", major);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is just a very cursory observation, but you set `fullyear[2]`, `fullyear[3]` and `fullyear[4]` the same in all cases. You can just set those once right after declaring `fullyear[5];` outside of your `if` statements.

Comment: This is what happens when a code is wrongly indented ...

Comment: You code as you give it cannot be compiled, what is your **real** code ?

Comment: My bad. I tried to fix it but already closed the question it said... but thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to store 3 names, 3 majors, and 3 SSNs, then you need to declare those arrays as

```
char name[3][20];   // 3 strings of 20 characters each
char major[3][20];
char ssn[3][20];
```

and they need to be declared *outside* of the body of the loop.

Then in your loop, you'd read each element as

```
scanf( "%19[^\n]%*c", name[i] ); // Read no more than 19 characters into each
...                              // object - this means you may need to do
scanf( "%19[^\n]%*c", major[i] );// some cleanup between each read if the user
...                              // entered more than 20 characters for a 
scanf( "%19[^\n]%*c", ssn[i] );  // given entry
```

When you compute the birth date, just replace each instance of `ssn` with `ssn[i]`, such as

```
memcpy(year, &ssn[i][0], 2);
...
memcpy(month, &ssn[i][2], 2);
```

etc.

You'll want at least two loops - one for all the input, and one for displaying the sorted output.  With only three elements, you shouldn't need to do an actual sort, just keep track of which index needs to come first and second.

You do have a severe structural problem in your code - the lines

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)

char name[20];
char major[50];
char ssn[20];
{
```

need to be changed to

```
char name[3][20];
char major[3][50];
char ssn[3][20];

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
```

What happened is you defined a loop with a single statement - the declaration of `name`.  Everything after that is outside of the loop.

Start with those changes, and hopefully that will help you move forward.

**EDIT**

An alternate approach to using 3 separate arrays would be to use a single array of a `struct` type:

```
struct student
{
  char name[20];
  char major[20];
  char ssn[20];
} students[3];

for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
  // read input
  ...
  scanf( "%19[^\n]%*c", students[i].name );
  ...
  scanf( "%19[^\n]%*c", students[i].major );
  ...
  scanf( "%19[^\n]%*c", students[i].ssn );
  ...
}

// "sort" entries

for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
{
  // print output
}
```

You get the idea - instead of expressions like `name[i]` or `major[i]`, you'd use `students[i].name`, `student[i].major`, etc.

Comment: The three arrays can be in the `for` body, difficult to be sure. And where is the `return 0;` ? it seems inside the `for` because there are 2' }' after, but that has no sense .. like the missing { to start the body of *main* ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. I am going to work on that today based on your adivce

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)

char name[20];
char major[50];
char ssn[20];
{
```

The brace should be under `for`, and it should include the three buffer definitions, like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    char name[20];
    char major[50];
    char ssn[20];

    // ....
}
```

Comment: For clarity, show the corrected version as well. :)

Comment: @lurker good luck to find a corrected version, the OP code does not even have a { to start the body of the *main*. The `return 0;` seems inside the `for` because of `}}`after but that has no sense ...

Comment: @bruno that is, indeed, a broader problem.

Comment: Thank you and I edited with the correct code (I figured how to add code on here now...)
also fixed that would work for loop